# Get disks count via powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, sccm

I have a strange behavior when I try to count how much drivers are connected to a workstation.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS> get-disk | select number, size

number          size
------          ----
 0  512110190592
 1 1000204886016

PS C:\WINDOWS> (get-disk | select number, size).count
2
```

So far, so good. Now, I'm going to filter it down to select my smallest drive

```
PS C:\WINDOWS> get-disk | Where-Object { $_.Size -lt 600GB } | select number, size

number         size
------         ----
 0 512110190592

PS C:\WINDOWS> (get-disk | Where-Object { $_.Size -lt 600GB } | select number, size).count
```

Where is my count? Shouldn't it return 1? It is working fine with other collections of one:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS> (get-process).count
196

PS C:\WINDOWS> (get-process powershell_ise ).count
1
```

Is it an issue with my disks object type?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS> Get-Disk |gm

TypeName: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk
```

Much confusion in my brain now!

Anyone has an idea what could go wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
(get-disk | Where-Object { $_.Size -lt 600GB }).Number.Count
```

This:

```
(get-disk | Where-Object { $_.Size -lt 600GB })
```

Is of type `CimInstance` and apparently it doesn't support `Count`

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same, the select is just for the example to make output easier to read here. My script doesn't actually filter anything.
I have a workaround by creating a custom PSobject, and it is working fine. I'm mostly wondering why this is not working out of the box.

Comment: It does work fine when I look at a property. Thanks!